# How can we archive/encrypt Robot Framework Test Reports

Tags: robotframework

My Robot reports contains sensitive information. I want to archive them for a security reason.

Anyone suggest me the way or process to archive/encrypt the robot reports??

Thanks,
Prasad Pasupuleti

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Are you trying to do this from within the robot framework (I don't know anything about it; I know for Django as an example, there are hooks so that the error reports can remove and possible encrypt/obfuscate sensitive information) or do you just want a suggested way to encrypt the files after the fact (e.g. piping through gpg or another encryption application if you're running on a Linux system and possibly Mac)

Answer (score 3):

use the `--outputdir` option to have the output files written to an empty directory. You can then zip/tar that whole directory into a single file that you can copy anywhere you want.

If you need the data encrypted you can use [GnuPG](https://www.gnupg.org/) or [bcrypt](http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/), or any of the other standard encryption tools.